# Reverse Polish Notation in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stack, calculator, rpn

I am currently trying to write a RPN calculator for an assignment and I'm having some problems. The method evaluateCountdown is meant to take in a string containing a mathematical expression written in Reverse Polish Notation and it's meant to return the result of evaluating the expression as a double.

For example: string "3.0 4.0 + 2.0 *" should return 14.0 as a double.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <stack>
 
class CountdownSolution {

std::vector<std::string> stringToVector(const std::string newString,const char token)
{
 std::vector<std::string> stringVector;
 
 size_t posLast = 0, pos = 0;
 while((pos = newString.find(token, pos)) != std::string::npos)
 {
   if(newString[pos] != newString[posLast])
     stringVector.push_back(newString.substr(posLast, pos - posLast));
   posLast = ++pos;
 }
 if(newString[posLast] != 0)
   stringVector.push_back(newString.substr(posLast));
 
 return stringVector;
}
 
double evaluateCountdown(const std::string& rpnString) {
   std::vector<std::string> rpnStringVector = stringToVector(rpnString,' ');
   std::stack<double> rpnStack;
   int i = 0;
   double temp;
   for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator t=rpnStringVector.begin(); t!=rpnStringVector.end(); ++t)
   {
       if(rpnStringVector[i] == "+"){
           temp = std::stod(rpnStringVector[i-2])+std::stod(rpnStringVector[i-1]);
           rpnStack.pop();
           rpnStack.pop();
           rpnStack.push(temp);
           i++;
           continue;
       } else if(rpnStringVector[i] == "-"){
           temp = std::stod(rpnStringVector[i-2])-std::stod(rpnStringVector[i-1]);
           rpnStack.pop();
           rpnStack.pop();
           rpnStack.push(temp);
           i++;
           continue;
       } else if(rpnStringVector[i] == "*"){
           temp = std::stod(rpnStringVector[i-2])*std::stod(rpnStringVector[i-1]);
           rpnStack.pop();
           rpnStack.pop();
           rpnStack.push(temp);
           i++;
           continue;
       } else if(rpnStringVector[i] == "/"){
           temp = std::stod(rpnStringVector[i-2])/std::stod(rpnStringVector[i-1]);
           rpnStack.pop();
           rpnStack.pop();
           rpnStack.push(temp);
           i++;
           continue;
       } else {
           rpnStack.push(std::stod(rpnStringVector[i]));
           i++;
           continue;
       }
   }
   return rpnStack.top();
   }
}
```

Out of the following 4 tests I only pass 1.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
 
#include <string>
 
int main() {
 
   int retval = 0;
  
   {
       double answer = evaluateCountdown(std::string("3.0 4.0 +"));
       if (answer == 7.0) {
           cout << "1) Pass: evaluated '3.0 4.0 +', got 7.0\n";
       } else {
           cout << "1) Fail: evaluated '3.0 4.0 +' expecting 7.0, but got " << answer << std::endl;
           ++retval;
       }
   }
  
   {
       double answer = evaluateCountdown(std::string("3.0 4.0 - 4.0 +"));
       if (answer == 3.0) {
           cout << "2) Pass: evaluated '3.0 4.0 - 4.0 +', got 3.0\n";
       } else {
           cout << "2) Fail: evaluated '3.0 4.0 - 4.0 +' expecting 3.0, but got " << answer << std::endl;
           ++retval;
       }
   }
  
   {
       double answer = evaluateCountdown(std::string("3.0 4.0 - 2.0 *"));
       if (answer == -2.0) {
           cout << "3) Pass: evaluated '3.0 4.0 - 2.0 *', got -2.0\n";
       } else {
           cout << "3) Fail: evaluated '3.0 4.0 - 2.0 *' expecting -2.0, but got " << answer << std::endl;
           ++retval;
       }
   }
      
 
   {
       double answer = evaluateCountdown(std::string("100 20 / 4 +"));
       if (answer == 9) {
           cout << "4) Pass: evaluated '100 20 / 4 +', got 9\n";
       } else {
           cout << "4) Fail: evaluated '100 20 / 4 +' expecting 9, but got " << answer << std::endl;
           ++retval;
       }
   }
 
   return retval;
}
```

This is my output of running the tests.

1. Pass: evaluated '3.0 4.0 +', got 7.0
2. Fail: evaluated '3.0 4.0 - 4.0 +' expecting 3.0, but got -1
3. Fail: evaluated '3.0 4.0 - 2.0 *' expecting -2.0, but got -1
4. Fail: evaluated '100 20 / 4 +' expecting 9, but got 5

I can see from my results that the for loop only iterates through the first 3 elements of the vector but I'm not sure why.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: For #2 through #4, looks like you are not processing beyond the first operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting your string works as expected, the problem is that you incorrectly manage the values on the stack. Instead of trying to re-read (and re-parse!) the values from the string vector (which might, in worst case, lead to evaluate an operator as a double, resulting in an exception) you should fetch your already parsed values from stack, apply the operator and push the result back, as follows:

```
double o2 = rpnStack.top();
rpnStack.pop();
double o1 = rpnStack.top();
rpnStack.pop();
rpnStack.push(o1 <op> o2);
```

Important at this point: As this is a stack, you pushed the first operand first and the second one last, so you need to pop in inverse order as well!

Some further issues about your code:

1. Floating point values disallow for precise math, even such a simple value like 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as it is periodic in binary, so all floating point math potentially comes with rounding issues – and in consequence you [cannot compare for exact (in-) equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison).
2. You don't need all those `continue`s if you don't have anything to skip anyway – any subsequent code is wrapped in an `else` anyway.
3. All those unnecessary braces within `main` make the code pretty inconvenient to read, you should drop them. Of course `answer` will then be multiply defined, but that can be solved by simply dropping the declaration on the subsequent calls (`double a = e(); a = e();`).
4. Applying the changes above you can simplify the loop with a range based loop:
    `for(auto& s : rpnStringVector)` and inside the loop body evaluate `s` (give it another name, if you like...) instead of `rpnStringVector[i]`.

You seem to have intended the functions being member of a class (`class CountdownSolution {`), actually being invalid code as you never close this class – you could profit from to avoid duplicate code and get a bit more efficient by avoiding copies:

```
class CountdownSolution
{
public:
    // use std::string_view so that we can operate
    // without partial copies (sub-strings!) entirely:
    double evaluate(std::string_view const& expression)
    {
        size_t posLast = 0;
        size_t pos = 0;
        while((pos = expression.find(' ', pos)) != std::string::npos)
        {
            if(expression[pos] != expression[posLast])
            {
                // evaluate immediately instead of adding to function
                doEvaluate(expression.substr(posLast, pos - posLast));
            }
            posLast = ++pos;
        }
        if(expression[posLast] != 0)
        {
            doEvaluate(expression.substr(posLast));
            posLast = ++pos;
        }
        auto result = m_stack.top();
        // clear the stack so that we can re-use the instance!
        m_stack.pop();
        return result;
    }

private:
    std::stack<double> m_stack; // make the stack a member!

    void doEvaluate(std::string_view const& token)
    {
        if(token == "+")
        {
            // structured binding - need C++17 for
            // unpacks the pair being returned to op1 and op2
            auto [op1, op2] = popOperands();
            m_stack.push(op1 + op2);
        }
        else if(token == "-")
        {
            auto [op1, op2] = popOperands();
            m_stack.push(op1 - op2);
        }
        else if(token == "*")
        {
            auto [op1, op2] = popOperands();
            m_stack.push(op1 * op2);
        }
        else if(token == "/")
        {
            auto [op1, op2] = popOperands();
            m_stack.push(op1 / op2);
        }
        else
        {
            // as using std::string_view, we cannot use std::stod
            auto end = &token.back() + 1;
            double tmp;
            // from charconv header:
            auto [last, ec] = std::from_chars(&token.front(), end, tmp);
            if(ec != std::errc() || last != end)
            {
                // invalid string!
                // best: throw an exception!

                // but assure an empty stack before so that we
                // can re-use the instance!
                // too bad there's no `clear` for...
                m_stack = std::stack<double>();

                // SHOULDN'T throw THAT but too lazy to
                // select the appropriate exceptions...
                // leaving this to you!
                // (use different ones for different errors, see
                // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars)
                throw ec;
            }
            m_stack.push(tmp);
        }
    }

    std::pair<double, double> popOperands()
    {
        std::pair<double, double> result;
        // as explained already: need to pop second operand first!
        result.second = m_stack.top();
        m_stack.pop();
        result.first = m_stack.top();
        m_stack.pop();
        return result;
    }
};
```

Admitted, having to use `std::from_chars` is too nice... If you don't like, you can revert the `std::string_view`s back to `std::string`s (still all `const` references), using `std::stod` again. You then copy the sub-strings again, but only one at a time (and you spare the vector). But that function can throw, and you might still keep your class re-usable afterwards, so you should do:

```
try
{
    m_stack.push(std::stod(token));
}
catch(...) // as we are re-throwing anyway we can catch unspecifically
{
    // clearing the stack again
    // that might fail on std::bad_alloc, but then we're out anyway... 
    m_stack = std::stack<double>();

    // just re-throw:
    throw;
}
```

Final recommendation: Don't just copy-paste, you won't learn anything from (but if you do so, not my problem...), try to understand, then re-write on your own. Feel free to leave a comment if something is unclear ;)